# Android FragmentManager extension function working

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I saw in Google IO code this extension function for FragmentManager.

```
/**
* Allows calls like
*
* `supportFragmentManager.inTransaction { add(...) }`
*/
inline fun FragmentManager.inTransaction(func: FragmentTransaction.() ->FragmentTransaction) 
{
    beginTransaction().func().commit()
}
```

It is used like this:

```
supportFragmentManager.inTransaction {
            add(R.id.fragment_container, OnboardingFragment())
        }
```

Can someone explain what type is this func variable in inTransaction method?

I know this is of type lambda but what is the argument of that lambda here "Fragmenttransaction.()"?

Answer (score 1):

I'll try to explain each statement meaning in `func: FragmentTransaction.() -> FragmentTransaction`

`func` is nothing but a variable name, it can be anything not necessarily `func`.

`FragmentTransaction.()` is the type of variable passed into method, meaning it is a extension of `FragmentTransaction`, with `.()` , the `lambda` is in scope of `FragmentTransaction` meaning inside lamba you will have access to `FragmentTransaction` using `this`, that is why you can directly access `add`, `replace` and other transaction methods inside lambda scope.

`-> FragmentTransaction` means this method/lambda will return value of type  `FragmentTransaction` which will be used by caller to get the `FramgmentTransaction`

`inline fun FragmentManager.inTransaction` is an extension function on FragmentManager, by calling `beginTransaction` it now has `FragmentTransaction` and calling func will apply necessary transformations to transaction and will return it which then used to commit the transaction.

**UPDATE**

when you call `beginTransaction()` it will return a `FragmentTransaction`, on which `func` can be called as extension `function`,

```
inline fun FragmentManager.inTransaction(func: FragmentTransaction.() ->FragmentTransaction) 
{
    val transaction: FragmentTransaction = beginTransaction()
    transaction.func().commit()
}
```

Take a look at below example for different ways of appending strings to `StringBuilder`

```
 //traditional way
 fun toString(stringBuilder: StringBuilder): String{
     return stringBuilder.toString()
 }
    
 fun StringBuilder.append1(): StringBuilder{
     append(1)
     return this
 }

 fun StringBuilder.append2(): StringBuilder{
     append(2)
     return this
 }
    
 //extenison as parameter
 fun toString(builder: StringBuilder.() -> StringBuilder): String{
    return builder().toString()
 }
    
 fun test(){
     //here based on your need , multiple extension functions are created
     val stringBuilder = StringBuilder()
     val s1 = toString(stringBuilder.append1())
     val s2 = toString(stringBuilder.append2())
     
     //modifying string builder extension dynamically
     val t1 = toString { append(1) }
     val t2 = toString { append(2) }
 }
```

Comment: thanks for explanation, I know return type of func lambda is FragmentTransaction but what is the parameter here?

Comment: I saw this example online here we are passing string builder to similar function: 
fun buildString(action: (StringBuilder).() -> Unit): String {
    val stringBuilder = StringBuilder()
    action(stringBuilder)
    return stringBuilder.toString()
}

So don't we have to pass FragmentTransaction object in func here like this: 
func(this) where this is FragmentTrasaction

Comment: `FragmentTransaction.()` is paramater which is a extension function of `FragmentTransaction`, basically you are passing code for extension function

Comment: Please check my 2nd comment

Comment: Thanks for your efforts but I am totally confused now, I am not getting that part that how come we are not passing anything in func() call and in the StringBuilder example we are passing stringbuilder in the same.

Comment: It's completely fine if you don't want to waste your time in this, thanks for your efforts :)

Comment: For clarification:
https://medium.com/@khadijahameed415/extension-function-in-kotlin-e3a3ed5920c4